# AWS Glue job hangs when calling the AWS Glue client API using boto3 from the context of a running AWS Glue Job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue

I'm trying to create a Glue Job that enumerates all tables in a database in my catalog. In order to do so I use the following code snippet:

```
session = boto3.Session(region_name='us-east-2')
glue = session.client('glue')
tables = glue.get_tables(
    DatabaseName='customer1'
)
print tables
```

The job hangs for about 15 minutes and the connection appears to be refused, because I eventually get the following error:

> botocore.vendored.requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout:
>   HTTPSConnectionPool(host='glue.us-east-2.amazonaws.com', port=443):
>   Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by
>   ConnectTimeoutError(, 'Connection to glue.us-east-2.amazonaws.com timed
>   out. (connect timeout=60)’))

This issue is specific to the glue API. I can use the S3 API with no problems.

I've gone through all my security groups and opened up all the ports to traffic from anywhere. I've even added self-referencing rules. But this is to no avail.

I can't figure out what could be causing the connection to be blocked. Is AWS specifically blocking glue requests?

Comment: I am running into the same issue.

Comment: I have the same problem when running glue boto client commands from Glue Dev Endpoint. However when running as a normal glue job all boto3 commands run successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem that boto3 calls to `glue` or `s3` were hanging and eventually timing out.

I fixed it by changing the subnet-id when creating the dev-endpoint. 
Initially I was using a subnet that routed traffic to an Internet Gateway. 
I switched to a subnet routing traffic to an internal NAT gateway. Hope this helps.

Comment: This has worked for you may be because you not assigned public-ip to your instance.

Answer (score 0):

[glue job times out when calling aws boto3 client api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54047044/glue-job-times-out-when-calling-aws-boto3-client-api/73708254#73708254)

Solution:
Just repeat what @darius matonas replied to make it straight, when you need to run a Glue job to get either the job you just created or other jobs' information, BEFORE you call boto3 -- something like get_job_run or get_job_runs, MAKE SURE create a new endpoint in VPC and assigne to same Subnet and Security Group that your Glue connection uses.